# Why do I get "05-20 10:41:10.242: ERROR/MapActivity(425): Couldn't get connection factory client "?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm running some tests on an Android app that involves Google Maps API and GPS and I get the following error message in LogCat:

> 05-20 10:41:10.242: ERROR/MapActivity(425): Couldn't get connection factory client

I already gave the right permissions in the Manifest and already tested some other activities involving maps and they worked just fine. But when I try to do something with GPS, I get this error message.

I've read on some forums that probably there is something wrong with my key, but I don't think that's the question because it already worked just fine many times.

Answer (score 1):

You can safely ignore this message. Everyone gets it. Since this comes from closed-source code, we do not know the origin of the message.